# Post Image to Facebook with custom message

Tags: android

I am using the next code to post an image to the user's Facebook wall:

```
private void postImageToWall(Session session) {

    // Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "demo.jpg");
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.frame_with_woman);
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putParcelable("source", image);
    parameters.putString("message", "my message for the page");
    Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/photos", parameters, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            LogService.log(TAG, "Successfully posted");
        }
    });
    request.executeAsync();

}
```

How can I make it so a "default" Facebook popup dialog appears (you know the ones, e.g. ***[this one](http://labs.thesedays.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/popup.jpg)***) thus letting the user enter the caption of the image, and not set a hard-coded one, like I am in the code above.

```
parameters.putString("message", "my message for the page");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following method for posting message

```
void PostFb()
      {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("name", getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        parameters.putString("link", "http://www.youtube.com");//Put Image URL Here


        facebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters,
                new DialogListener() {

                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                    }

                    public void onCancel() {

                    }
                });
    }
```

let me know if it works.Because it shows preview of any url you enter at this line `parameters.putString("link", "http://www.youtube.com");`

Before doing this declare below parameters

Declare this above class name  private Facebook facebook;

& Do initialization like this at `onCreate` method

```
facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
```

Comment: what type is the "facebook" object ?

Comment: Apparently it works, it shows the popup. The problem is I can't seem to attach the image to the post. putString("link", "http://www.youtube.com"); ... I have the image locally, in memory, I don't have it posted anywhere.

Comment: Nope. Apparently there isn't a solution by which you can attach an image (binary) to the dialog, unless you upload the image onto a Webservice and then attach the link of the image to the dialog. Apparently the only way it can be done is the way I said in the question, that code works, but with default message. Stupid FB Android API

Comment: @AndreiBogdan oh! so you uploaded your image to webservice?

Comment: No, the API can't be changed (it wasn't created by me). I just used the posting method with default message. C'est la vie.

Comment: @AndreiBogdan hmm,in my case i was getting `ImageUrl` from webservice

Answer (score 0):

User this tag for description posting,

```
postParams.putString("caption", mes);
```

This is my complete code for sharing image with text in facebook wall,

```
private void facebookImagePosting(String imageUrl, String mes) {
    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    postParams.putString("access_token", accessToken);

    byte[] data = null;

    URL aURL;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    try {
        aURL = new URL(imageUrl);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 8192);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    data = baos.toByteArray();
    postParams.putByteArray("picture", data);
    postParams.putString("caption", mes);
    Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
                Log.e("Facebook Error Message", error.getErrorMessage());
            } else {
            Log.e("Success Message", "Decision posted successfully!");

            }
        }
    };
    Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/photos",
            postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();
}
```